# Has many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are all kinds of references out there to building a Has_Many through relationship in Ruby on Rails, but very little information on how to handle that relationship.

I have a Users table with the following variables:

```
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "confirmation_token"
t.datetime "confirmed_at"
t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
```

Then I have a Wikis table:

```
t.string   "title"
t.datetime "published_at"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.text     "body"
```

And, I have a Relationships table to join the two:

```
t.integer "wiki_id"
t.integer "user_id"
t.boolean "creator_created"
t.boolean "collaborator"
```

The Relationships Class belongs_to each of the other classes:

```
belongs_to :users
belongs_to :wikis
```

The other two have has_many, through code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :relationships
  has_many :wikis, through: :relationships
```

and vice versa.

So my question is, now what? How can I call these various classes and their variables? user.wiki doesn't seem to work, or user.relationship.wiki; even relationship.created_creator pulls error messages!

In particular, I want to be able to find out if a user created a wiki so that that user may edit that wiki. I've tried to create a method for this in the user model:

```
def creator?(wiki, user)
    Relationship.where(wiki_id: wiki.id, user_id:user.id).creator_created
end
```

When I call it from a policy file, I get the error:

```
undefined method `creator_created' for #      <ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Relationship:0xbb19b84>
```

Can anyone help me use my has_many, through relationship? How can I refer to a wiki that is related to a user, or to the creator_created field that is related to both?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A `has_many` relationship returns a collection. Rails uses the plural form of the association name to access the related objects.

To get a user's wikis, just do:

`user.wikis`

To find whether a user created a wiki, you'll need to use the Relationship:

`user.wikis.where(relationships: {creator_created: true})`

This shows how you can chain scopes onto associations.

This can be further simplified by adding a scope to the `Wiki` model:

`scope :creator_created, -> { where(relationships: {creator_created: true}) }`

which allows:

`user.wikis.creator_created`

It can be quite helpful to add `.to_sql` to the end of the expression to see the generated SQL statement.

Much of this is covered in the Rails Guide [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

**EDIT**

The error message "NameError: uninitialized constant User::Wikis" occurs due to an error in the `Relationship` model. `belongs_to` associations use the singular form to specify the related model, so change them to:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :wiki
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I'm still getting the error "uninitialized constant User::Wikis". In the Rails console, I get the error "NoMethodError: undefined method `wikis' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class". Any ideas?

Comment: I realized I wasn't specifying a single user, but even when I did (User.last), I got the error "NameError: uninitialized constant User::Wikis"

Comment: You are so close :) See my edit. The whole plural/singular business in Rails is very arbitrary. Once you've learned the conventions it will be second nature.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Relationship.where(wiki_id: wiki.id, user_id:user.id, creator_created: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.where(...)` returns a *collection* of model objects.

```
def creator?(wiki, user)
  # Raises error, as a model instance method (creator_created) is
  # called on a collection:
  Relationship.where(wiki_id: wiki.id, user_id:user.id).creator_created
end
```

In the code above, an attempt is being made to call `.creator_created` on a *collection* of `Relationship` objects (assuming objects are found matching the conditions given to `.where(...)`).

`.creator_created` is a method of a *single* `Relationship` object. It's not possible to call it on a collection of `Relationship`s.

Modifying the given `creator?` method to take this into account would give:

```
def creator?(wiki, user) 
  relationships = Relationship.where(wiki_id: wiki.id, user_id: user.id)
  if relationships.empty?
    raise "No matching relationships found for wiki: '#{wiki}'"
  end
  # Use the first element from the relationships collection
  relationship = relationships[0]
  relationship.creator_created
end
```

**However**, given the name of that method, I suspect this might be a more readable solution:

```
def creator?(wiki, user)
  user.relationships.find_by(wiki_id: wiki.id).creator_created
end
```

Compare `.find_by(...)` to `.where(...)`. `find_by` returns only a single model instance (if a match is found). [`.find_by` docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) and [`.where` docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) have example code.

Comment: Hi Eliot, thanks for this . . . I've tried your last def creator?, and it doesn't pass anything. In rails console, I can get a response, but it says that the result is 'nil', even though when I ask for the relationship record itself it shows a record with the correct wiki_id and user_id and creator_created:true.